# Sum of Multiples of Numbers Greater Or Equal to Target, Optimization

Tags: algorithm, vector, multiplication, subset-sum

Given an equation

Like 2(p<sub>1</sub>) + 3(p<sub>2</sub>) + 7(p<sub>3</sub>) >= 257

I need to find all possible combinations of p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub>
such the above statement is true and the resulting sum ( left hand side of the equation ) is minimal where all x<sub>n</sub> were known.

I tried looking up algorithms for general cases like

(x<sub>1</sub>)(p<sub>1</sub>) + (x<sub>2</sub>)(p<sub>2</sub>) + (x<sub>3</sub>)(p<sub>4</sub>) + ... + (x<sub>n</sub>)(p<sub>n</sub>) >= target

And I came across the Knapsack problem and Subset-Sum algorithm solutions, but they weren't exactly like this problem.

I tried before using an algorithm in Python 3.x that has lower-bound values for p<sub>n</sub>, but it still runs in O( ridiculous ) time complexity.

Obviously all numbers here are natural numbers, otherwise there would be infinite solutions.

Comment: This is more maths related than programming.

Comment: This is an unbounded *linear programming* problem. Usually, in LP, you have an objective function that is linear in its variables, and is what you want to optimize.  Printing out an infinite number of candidates seems awfully greedy. I suggest you look up LP.

Comment: It's worse than standard LP because of the integer constraint - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible approaches, depending on whether the Pi have to be >= 0. The case with Pi >= 0 is more sensible, so I will consider it first.

Treat this as dynamic programming, where you work from left to right along the equation. Looking at the larger equation in your comment, first of all create a list of the contributions from p0: 0, 5, 10, 15... 190384760, and beside them the value of p0 that produces them: 0, 1, 2, ... 190384760/5.

Now use this table to work out the values of 5p0 + 7p1 possible by combining the first two: 0, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14.... and keep the value of p1 needed to produce them.

Working from right to left you will end up with a table of the values up to just over 190384755 that can be created by positive integer combinations of p0..p8. You obviously only care about the largest one >= 190384755. Consider all possible values of the p8 contribution, subtract these from 190384755, and look in the table for p0..p7 to see which of these are possible. This gives you all possible values of p8, and for each of these you can recursively repeat the process to print out all possible values of p7, and so on repeat the recursion to provide all values of p0..p8 that yields the lowest value just over 190384755. This is very similar to the pseudo-polynomial algorithm for subset sum.

If the Pi can be < 0, then the achievable values are all multiples of the gcd of the Pi, which is very likely to be all integers, and there are an infinite number of solutions for this. If this is really what you want, you can start by reading about the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the given example is just a toy case.

If not, exhaustive search is quite feasible: the minimal sum is bounded by 259 (combination 0, 0, 37), and there are less than a half million combinations under this bound.

In addition, if you set two variables, say p2 and p3, such that 3(p2) + 7(p3) < 257, it is an easy matter to find the smallest p1 such that 2(p1) + 3(p2) + 7(p3) >= 257. You will just have to try 3200 (p2, p3) combinations or so.

Comment: I see what you are saying and I tried that before, (yes, it just a dummy case), and it might work for this case, which is just an arbitrary example. I'm looking for a general algorithm that will solve these kinds of problems quicker than an exhaustive search. This method will probably be insufficient for an equations like:

5p0 + 7p1 + 10p2 + 28p3 61p4+ 342p5 + 374p6 381p7 + 456p8 >= 190384755